# Microsoft Teams intermittent issue responding to a task module task/fetch in Node.js, from a Teams meeting chat adaptive card submit

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

We have an intermittent issue responding to a Microsoft Teams task module **task/fetch** in Node.js, from a Teams meeting chat adaptive card submit.

In other words: when a button press ('submit') is sent from an adaptive card to the Node.js server, from a Teams chat window, and picked up in a **handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch** method of a JS class that extends **TeamsActivityHandler**, the Teams client / application is intermittently rendering an adaptive card which has not been created on the server. When this incorrect adaptive card / modal is not rendered, the adaptive card we've created is rendered as expected; also, if we close the incorrect adaptive card / modal with the top right cross, the correct modal is then subsequently rendered to the screen.

This issue usually appears to manifest while using the Windows desktop client.

Any assistance, suggestions, guidance, or advise on what may be happening here would be gratefully received!

An image of the incorrect adaptive card / modal that gets intermittently returned is added to this post below, and is similar to the adaptive card / modal that we would see when adding up custom 'bot application' to the meeting, via the Teams UI.

[Click here for the incorrect adaptive card / modal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te7hP.jpg)

Comment: Please track this issue from here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1305499/intermittent-issue-responding-to-a-task-module-tas